# How to get the text value in a div html by clicking on button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to get the text between the div tag by clicking on the button event

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="pricing-table pricing-secondary">
        <div class="price-header">
            <h3 class="title text-white">Gold Plan</h3>
            <div class="price">
                <span class="dollar">&#8377</span> 7000
            </div>
            <span class="permonth">3 months</span>
        </div>
        <div class="price-footer">
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" href="javascript:void(0);">Book an
                Online Appointment</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="pricing-table pricing-third">
        <div class="price-header">
            <h3 class="title text-white">Diamond Plan</h3>
            <div class="price text-primary">
                <span class="dollar">&#8377</span> 12000
            </div>
            <span class="permonth">6 Months</span>
        </div>
        <div class="price-footer">
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" href="javascript:void(0);">Book an
                Online Appointment</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="pricing-table pricing-fourth">
        <div class="price-header">
            <h3 class="title text-white">Platinum Plan</h3>
            <div class="price text-white">
                <span class="dollar">&#8377</span> 15000
            </div>
            <span class="permonth">12 Months</span>
        </div>
        <div class="price-footer">
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" href="javascript:void(0);">Book an
                Online Appointment</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this type of divs its around three or four I want to detect the value `12000` and the month `6 Months` by clicking on this button

How can I achieve that.

Comment: The div's are inside with one button or multiple buttons and divs for each ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping same as shown in the above one.

Comment: You have this type of div's okay! but are you all same classes and you want to click on the button to get ITS price and permonth - its not like you click once and get all the month and prices - hope this makes sense ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping but price and months may vary

Comment: `&#8377` should be `&#8377;` and also, do you need that symbol when going for *price*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(".price-footer .btn").on( "click", function(event) {
  const parent = $(this).parents('.pricing-table');
  
  const priceText = $('.price', parent).text().trim();
  const priceParts = priceText.split(' ');
  
  console.log(`priceText: ${priceParts[1]}`);
  // Output: "priceText: 12000"
  
  const permonthText = $('.permonth', parent).text().trim();
  console.log(`permonthText: ${permonthText}`);
  // Output: "permonthText: 6 Months"
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/MWybEEr

Answer (score 0):

You can add `id`s to the elements you want to extract the contents of, then you can use `document.getElementById(id)` to get those elements, and use `.innerText` to extract the string contents.

Then with a `string.replace()` you can remove any non-numerical values, and convert the monetary value into a number.

```js
const dollarAmount = parseFloat(document.getElementById("dollar-info").innerText.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''))

const month = document.getElementById("month-info").innerText

console.log(dollarAmount)
console.log(month)
```

```html
<div class="price-header">
  <h3 class="title text-white">Diamond Plan</h3>
  <div id="dollar-info" class="price text-primary">
    <span class="dollar">&#8377</span>12000.80
  </div>
  <span id="month-info" class="permonth">6 Months</span>
</div>
```

Comment: will it change according to the above code and I also need this on the button click

Comment: It depends what you want to use to select the HTML elements that you are trying to scrape - do you want to only hit specific divs, in which case you could add an id for each on, as in this answer? Otherwise if you want to scrape all the divs with the "price" class, you could use `getElementsByClassName` which returns a list of all html elements with that class, which you could then get the contents of. Let me know exactly what output (and how much) you want from your updated code in the question and I'll update this answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have many price tables you can loop each table as below example. You can wrap you data in a certain class and get the text value of that class div. Click the button on the to get the value in the example below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.pricing-table').each(function(){
    var $table = $(this);
    $table.on('click', '.btn-primary', function(){
      var price = $table.find('.price').text().trim();
      var permonth = $table.find('.permonth').text().trim();
      
      alert("price is " + price + " for " + permonth);
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="pricing-table pricing-third">
        <div class="price-header">
            <h3 class="title text-white">Diamond Plan</h3>
                <div class="price text-primary">
                    <span class="dollar">&#8377</span> 12000
                </div>
                <span class="permonth">6 Months</span>
        </div>
        <div class="price-footer">
            <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" href="javascript:void(0);">Book an
            Online Appointment</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.pricing-table').each(function(){` is useless. jQuery already operates on collections and it also provides `$(event.delegateTarget)` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many options to do this. Here is my example with the snippet and code sandbox.

```js
// jquery

const findValues = (target, value) => target.parents().eq(1).find(value);

$(document).on("click", ".btn", (e) => {
  const $target = $(e.target);

  // dollar is optional
  const $dollar = findValues($target, ".dollar");
  const $value = findValues($target, ".value");
  const $month = findValues($target, ".permonth");

  $("#test").text(`${$dollar.text()} ${$value.text()} ${$month.text()}`);
});

// // vanilla js

const test1 = document.querySelector("#test1");

document.querySelectorAll(".btn").forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", ({ target }) => {
    const nodes = target.parentNode.parentNode;
    const dollar1 = nodes.querySelector(".dollar");
    const value1 = nodes.querySelector(".value");
    const month1 = nodes.querySelector(".permonth");

    test1.innerText = `${dollar1.textContent} ${value1.textContent} ${month1.textContent}`;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="pricing-table pricing-secondary">
      <div class="price-header">
        <h3 class="title text-white">Gold Plan</h3>
        <div class="price">
          <span class="dollar">&#8377</span> <span class="value">7000</span>
        </div>
        <span class="permonth">3 months</span>
      </div>
      <div class="price-footer">
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg"
          href="javascript:void(0);">Book an
          Online Appointment</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="pricing-table pricing-third">
      <div class="price-header">
        <h3 class="title text-white">Diamond Plan</h3>
        <div class="price text-primary">
          <span class="dollar">&#8377</span> <span class="value">12000</span>
        </div>
        <span class="permonth">6 Months</span>
      </div>
      <div class="price-footer">
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg"
          href="javascript:void(0);">Book an
          Online Appointment</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
    <div class="pricing-table pricing-fourth">
      <div class="price-header">
        <h3 class="title text-white">Platinum Plan</h3>
        <div class="price text-white">
          <span class="dollar">&#8377</span> <span class="value">15000</span>
        </div>
        <span class="permonth">12 Months</span>
      </div>
      <div class="price-footer">
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg"
          href="javascript:void(0);">Book an
          Online Appointment</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="test"></div>
  <div id="test1"></div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-voice-2w640?file=/src/index.js